# How to use Graphql Vue Apollo on older IOS / older browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, vue-apollo

I just realize and noticing that my vue app doesn't work well on some older browsers (ios 9 for example). I used the [vue-apollo](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com) to get data from graphql api using django graphene , but it doesn't event get called on the first load when i debug it.

Previously i get error like "fetch is not found globally", but then i already fix it by adding "unfetch" to the ApolloClient config. But i still can't see on xhr network the api get called. I haven't try with isomorphic-fetch

Here's my code for the apollo client config:

```
// src/utils/graphql.js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import fetch from 'unfetch'

export default new ApolloClient({
  // Provide the URL to the API server.
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: '/api/', fetch: fetch }),
  // Using a cache for blazingly
  // fast subsequent queries.
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true
});
```

and i specify it like so in the main.js

```
import apolloClient from '../utils/graphql'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'

Vue.use(VueApollo);

Vue.config.silent = true

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
  defaultOptions: {
    $loadingKey: "loading"
  }
})
```

This is example of the apollo that i use inside the main.js as well using the smart query:

```
apollo: {
  currentUser: {
    query: GET_LOGGED_USER,
    skipQuery() {
      return this.skipUser
    }
  }
}
```

How can i make it work on ios 9 / any older browser?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after debugging it for two days, I finally found out the issue. So it turns out that i need to add and configure [babel/polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) as well in order to make it works, and add it to the entry point of my app.

Hope everyone who has the same issue can learn from my mistake lol